# session destroying in codeigniter after redirecting

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my login controller i have stored all user data in session. i have verified also by printing

> all_userdata();

when redirected  to another controller **home** the session was destroyed. please help me to solve this issue. The session data is as follows.

```
Array
(
[session_id] => 11c8450a10e6f944c97f13841ccea0c2
[ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
[last_activity] => 1408779229
[user_data] => 
[id] => 432
[empid] => 1024
[username] => 
[email] => gvsvinayak@gmail.com
[fullname] => G V S Vinayak
[usertype] => staff
[logged_in] => 1
[access] => Array
    (
        [menu] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Home
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Blocked Domains
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [id] => 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => List of Companies
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [id] => 3
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Full Registrations
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 3
                        [id] => 4
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Partial Registrations
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 3
                        [id] => 5
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Staff
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [id] => 6
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Add Satff
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 6
                        [id] => 8
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => View All
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 6
                        [id] => 9
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Cloud Instances
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [id] => 7
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_title] => Search
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [id] => 10
                    )

            )

        [companytabs] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => Company Profile
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => VM Details
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => Support
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 3
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => Monitors
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 4
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => Users
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 5
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => Orders
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 6
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [tab_name] => Invoices
                        [can_edit] => 1
                        [can_delete] => 1
                        [can_view] => 1
                        [id] => 7
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 3):

This is a same kind of issue I had while testing on **IE7/IE8**.
And I had found a **solution** here: http://www.philsbury.co.uk/blog/code-igniter-sessions

This is an issue that someone made a **3rd party fix for**, it patches the Session Controller. Checkout what the above link says,

**Solution:**

1) For this you have to create a new file **Session.php** in **application/libraries** directory.

2) Copy the below **source code** in the newly created file.

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
* Session class using native PHP session features and hardened against session fixation.
*
* @package     CodeIgniter
* @subpackage  Libraries
* @category    Sessions
* @author      Dariusz Debowczyk
* @link        http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
*/
class CI_Session {

    var $flash_key = 'flash'; // prefix for "flash" variables (eg. flash:new:message)

    function CI_Session()
    {
        $this->object =& get_instance();
        log_message('debug', "Native_session Class Initialized");
        $this->_sess_run();
    }

    /**
    * Regenerates session id
    */
    function regenerate_id()
    {
        // copy old session data, including its id
        $old_session_id = session_id();
        $old_session_data = $_SESSION;

        // regenerate session id and store it
        session_regenerate_id();
        $new_session_id = session_id();

        // switch to the old session and destroy its storage
        session_id($old_session_id);
        session_destroy();

        // switch back to the new session id and send the cookie
        session_id($new_session_id);
        session_start();

        // restore the old session data into the new session
        $_SESSION = $old_session_data;

        // update the session creation time
        $_SESSION['regenerated'] = time();

        // session_write_close() patch based on this thread
        // http://www.codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/1624/
        // there is a question mark ?? as to side affects

        // end the current session and store session data.
        session_write_close();
    }

    /**
    * Destroys the session and erases session storage
    */
    function destroy()
    {
        unset($_SESSION);
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
        {
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
        }
        session_destroy();
    }

    /**
    * Reads given session attribute value
    */    
    function userdata($item)
    {
        if($item == 'session_id'){ //added for backward-compatibility
            return session_id();
        }else{
            return ( ! isset($_SESSION[$item])) ? false : $_SESSION[$item];
        }
    }

    /**
    * Sets session attributes to the given values
    */
    function set_userdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Erases given session attributes
    */
    function unset_userdata($newdata = array())
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => '');
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Starts up the session system for current request
    */
    function _sess_run()
    {
        session_start();

        $session_id_ttl = $this->object->config->item('sess_expiration');

        if (is_numeric($session_id_ttl))
        {
            if ($session_id_ttl > 0)
            {
                $this->session_id_ttl = $this->object->config->item('sess_expiration');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session_id_ttl = (60*60*24*365*2);
            }
        }

        // check if session id needs regeneration
        if ( $this->_session_id_expired() )
        {
            // regenerate session id (session data stays the
            // same, but old session storage is destroyed)
            $this->regenerate_id();
        }

        // delete old flashdata (from last request)
        $this->_flashdata_sweep();

        // mark all new flashdata as old (data will be deleted before next request)
        $this->_flashdata_mark();
    }

    /**
    * Checks if session has expired
    */
    function _session_id_expired()
    {
        if ( !isset( $_SESSION['regenerated'] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['regenerated'] = time();
            return false;
        }

        $expiry_time = time() - $this->session_id_ttl;

        if ( $_SESSION['regenerated'] <=  $expiry_time )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Sets "flash" data which will be available only in next request (then it will
    * be deleted from session). You can use it to implement "Save succeeded" messages
    * after redirect.
    */
    function set_flashdata($key, $value)
    {
        $flash_key = $this->flash_key.':new:'.$key;
        $this->set_userdata($flash_key, $value);
    }

    /**
    * Keeps existing "flash" data available to next request.
    */
    function keep_flashdata($key)
    {
        $old_flash_key = $this->flash_key.':old:'.$key;
        $value = $this->userdata($old_flash_key);

        $new_flash_key = $this->flash_key.':new:'.$key;
        $this->set_userdata($new_flash_key, $value);
    }

    /**
    * Returns "flash" data for the given key.
    */
    function flashdata($key)
    {
        $flash_key = $this->flash_key.':old:'.$key;
        return $this->userdata($flash_key);
    }

    /**
    * PRIVATE: Internal method - marks "flash" session attributes as 'old'
    */
    function _flashdata_mark()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':new:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 2)
            {
                $new_name = $this->flash_key.':old:'.$parts[1];
                $this->set_userdata($new_name, $value);
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * PRIVATE: Internal method - removes "flash" session marked as 'old'
    */
    function _flashdata_sweep()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':old:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 2 && $parts[0] == $this->flash_key)
            {
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

3) Then load the library,

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting in this parameter in config file:

```
$config['cookie_domain']= '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated following values in config.php to solve the problem:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = 'mydomain.com';   // enter your domain name

$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE; // set "TRUE" only for https sites
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a best practice to store sessions in database using `$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'` .

First the config,

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'your_sessions_table';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'yoursite_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

then the cookies,

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'yourcookie';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'cookie.domain'; //use your domain name.  For multisite configuration use '.yourdomain.com'
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

finally, create a sessions table,

```
CREATE TABLE `your_sessions_table` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This way, you will never lose a session untill you call

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is by Codeigniter version you have. The best way is editing the session writing and reading.Open this file

> system/libraries/Session/session.php

Go the line no 281

```
ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);
```

Replace  session.name by session.id

```
ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);
```

Comment: This worked for me in CodeIgniter version 3.0.6. Thanks @gangi

Answer (score 0):

I set to both of the option and then only it worked in Codeigniter 3.1.0

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = 'mydomain.com';   // enter your domain name

$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE; // set "TRUE" only for https sites
```

The best way is editing the session writing and reading

```
system/libraries/Session/session.php
```

Go the line no 281

```
ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);
```

Replace session.name by session.id

```
ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);
```